# How to prevent named anchor from introducing a line break

Tags: html, css, anchor

In the following code snippet:

```
<a name="top"></a>
<div class="topbar">
  <img src="banner.jpg" alt="The Group Company" width="100%" />
  <div class="printOnly">
    <center><b>Printed from www.company.com</b></center>
  </div>
</div>
```

the named anchor (`<a name="top"></a>`) introduces a line break before the **topbar** div. Is there a way to prevent this? For a variety of reasons it is essential that the named anchor be located above the div containing the banner image.

I have tried using CSS  to set the **height** of the anchor to **0px** and **display** to **none**, but this renders he anchor non-functional (i.e. linking to **#top** from elsewhere in the page no longer works).

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: As per Giorgio's earlier comments, setting the font-size to 0px solves the problem.

Comment: Those comments weren't mine, and I would definitely not advise that ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Actually, using an anchor to link to a certain part on the page is [obsolete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-name). You can use the [global id attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes#attr-id) instead. That also fixes your problem as you don't have to add extra dom elements:

```
<div class="topbar" id="top">...</div>
```

Somewhere else:

```
<a href="#top">Go to top</a>
```

Easy does it!

Comment: Some more info: Setting `display:none` will prevent an element from being rendered. The problem you're facing is not that the `a` tag is introducing a line break but that the `div` tag is a refusing to be on the same line as  the `a` tag. The `div` is a block level element by default and `a` is an inline. See http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_blocks.asp for more. giorgio's solution will work for you but you should know about this.

Answer (score 0):

Make the div `<div class="topbar">` inline,

```css
.topbar{
  display:inline-block;
  }
```

```html
<a name="top"></a>
<div class="topbar">
  <img src="banner.jpg" alt="The Group Company" width="100%" />
  <div class="printOnly">
    <center><b>Printed from www.company.com</b></center>
  </div>
</div>
```